# Proof of $\lceil x \rceil + \lceil y \rceil \geq \lceil x + y \rceil$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have been trying to prove

$$
\lceil x \rceil + \lceil y \rceil  \geq \lceil x + y \rceil
$$

by using

$$
x \leq \lceil x \rceil < x+1,\\
y \leq \lceil y \rceil < y+1,\\
x + y \leq \lceil x+y \rceil < x + y + 1,\\
x + y \leq \lceil x \rceil + \lceil y \rceil < x + y + 2
$$

where $\lceil x \rceil, \lceil y \rceil, \lceil x + y \rceil$, and $\lceil x \rceil + \lceil y \rceil$ are unique integers satisfying their respective conditions.  I have been playing around with these inequalities, but have not made much progress towards a complete proof.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding $\lceil x \rceil \ge x$ to $\lceil y \rceil \ge y$ we get $$\lceil x \rceil + \lceil y \rceil \ge x + y.$$ This shows that the LHS is an integer greater than $x + y$. Since by the definition $ \lceil x  + y\rceil$ is the *smallest* integer greater than $x + y$, then necessarily $$ \lceil x \rceil +  \lceil y \rceil \ge  \lceil x + y\rceil.$$

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed something so simple.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused...  How does the inequality prove the original inequality?

Comment: No problem, I am editing my answer with more details.

Comment: Ahhhh... I see it now.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Comment: should that last line be ceil(x) + ceil(y) >= ceil(x+y)?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo!